# Laravel Structure - Where to place custom API methods?

Tags: php, laravel, directory-structure

I'm looking to implement MYOB OAuth API to my application which will run via a cronjob.

(**Reference:** http://myob-technology.github.io/AccountRight_OAUTH_sample_php/)

According to the laravel structure, which folder would be most appropriate to place this kind of code in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel you can place your API codes anywhere you want. But I feel more comfortable keeping my API code in `Controllers` directory.

Basic Directory and File Structure I follow

```
|- Http
 `|- Controllers
   `|- API
     ` - ApiController.php
       - OtherApiControllers.php
```

So basically I create a directory `API` to keep all the API controllers
The `ApiController.php` is extended by all other api controllers. The reason is I place some logics which all the other class will inherit.

For example:

```
class ApiController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
      # Setting Header
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    }
}
```

So yeah, I will recommend to follow this structure as I've been following this structure for almost two years and its going great.